# have django setup to use /django/ path from http://localhost/django/

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I have this WSGIScriptAlias /django/  /path/to/app in my Apache2 virtualhost config.

I used django-admin startproject myapp to create the project.
But when I go to http://localhost/django/ I get a 404 error via Django
If I change the virtualhost config to just / and restart apache2. It works but I use that for other things hence the reason for virtualhost and /django/ sub-path. But it seems that Django is working just not from the correct path.

```
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost/django/
    Using the URLconf defined in djangoexamplecom.urls, Django tried 
    these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    The empty path didn't match any of these.
    You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your 
    Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will 
    display a standard 404 page.
```

I am guessing when running django-admin startproject it expects the app to run at default URL i.e. http://localhost/   no sub-path?

Do I need to edit url.py or settings.py to use /django/?

Comment: Yes - do you want your /django/ route to be the base root for where your project directory is stored?

Comment: well, that path is actually just the alias.  So I assume that means to the project it is the base path? If so, then yes.